# Finding time difference between two times in different rows

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2012

Scenario: Database for Biometric device. It inserts

```
EmpId, EmpName, DepName, RecTime, RecDate
```

It gets inserted when User Enters office and swipes finger and then 2nd time when he leaves office. RecTime saves Entry time then Exit time.

Problem:

I want to calculate total time a person has worked but finding difference between RecTime in first record being inserted and 2nd record being inserted, in minutes and hours.

I tried DateDiff function, DateSub etc but nothing worked

Comment: Are the `EmpId` same in both cases

Comment: Have down-voted due to no DDL and now sample data

Answer (score 0):

Not going to solve your problem as there is insufficient data to do so.
The approach pattern I would follow is;

```
CREATE TABLE #EmpLogging 
(
    LogID   INT,
    EmpId   INT, 
    EmpName VARCHAR(50), 
    DepName VARCHAR(50), 
    RecTime TIME, 
    RecDate DATE
)
INSERT INTO #EmpLogging
SELECT  1,  1,  'Fred',     'Legal',        '08:00:00', '2013-01-01'    UNION ALL
SELECT  2,  2,  'Susan',    'Marketing',    '08:03:00', '2013-01-01'    UNION ALL
SELECT  3,  1,  'Fred',     'Legal',        '17:00:00', '2013-01-01'    UNION ALL
SELECT  4,  2,  'Susan',    'Marketing',    '17:55:00', '2013-01-01'    

;WITH EmpSequence AS
(
    SELECT *
            ,EmpSeq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpId ORDER BY RecDate, RecTime)
    FROM #EmpLogging    
)
,EndTime AS
(
    SELECT   E1.*
            ,OutTime    = E2.RecTime
            ,OutDate    = E2.RecDate
    FROM EmpSequence    E1
    LEFT
    JOIN EmpSequence    E2  ON  E1.EmpId = E2.EmpId
                            AND E1.EmpSeq = E2.EmpSeq - 1
)
SELECT *
        ,MINUTETimeFrame = DATEDIFF(MI, RecTime, OutTime)
FROM EndTime
```

[image]